# BufferedReader stuck on read. Wont read from Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

Here

```
try
{
    System.out.println("testIN");
    Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.16", 8090);
    while (socket.isConnected())
    {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
        printWriter.println("[05]");
        printWriter.println("\n");
        System.out.println(printWriter.checkError());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        if(bufferedReader.ready())
            System.out.println("READ: "+bufferedReader.read());
        else
            System.out.println("error");
        bufferedReader.close();
        socket.close();
        break;
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

what needs to change so that I can read the server's response. I dont have access to the server's code and it is hosted locally.

Comment: I do not see any readline statement in your Code at all ... could you check you code please ...

Comment: read and readline both didnt work

Comment: Which line is it stuck on?  If it is stuck on `System.out.println("READ: "+bufferedReader.read());`, this means the server hasn't sent anything, or you've read everything that is there to be read.

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be the problem. @SteveSmith I need to find out more about the server side code first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
        System.out.println("testIN");
        Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.16", 8090);
        while (socket.isConnected()) {
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
            printWriter.println("[05]");
            printWriter.println("\n");
            System.out.println(printWriter.checkError());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String data = null;
            if ((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("READ: " + data);
            else
                System.out.println("error");
            bufferedReader.close();
            socket.close();
            break;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Please add as to what you find in the OPs code that was the issue, and why you think your answer would solve the problem. Serving code on a platter never helps anyone learn or understand (in most cases)